# How to improve Pong AI with limited game state checks?

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, heuristics, pong

I'm currently developing a Pong game for a school project. **One rule I have is that the AI can only check the game state once every second**.

Currently, the AI operates on two simple rules:

- **(A)** If the ball is moving away from the AI, it returns to the center of the board.
- **(B)** If the ball is coming toward the AI, it tries to catch it and then returns to the center.

The physics of the game is pretty simple, if the ball hits a wall the velocity in x is reversed. If the ball hits a paddle, the ball is given a new velocity based on how far from the center of the paddle the collision occurred. The ball always travel at a constant speed.

```
    /* Update the angle of the ball based on where it hits the paddle */
    update_ball_velocity(paddle, normal) {
        const expanded =
            new physics.Rectangle(
                paddle.position.x - this.ball.size.x / 2,
                paddle.position.y - this.ball.size.y / 2,
                paddle.size.x + this.ball.size.x,
                paddle.size.y + this.ball.size.y,
                0,
                0
            );
        const ball_center =
            new physics.Vector(
                this.ball.position.x + this.ball.size.x / 2,
                this.ball.position.y + this.ball.size.y / 2
            );
        const paddle_center =
            new physics.Vector(
                expanded.position.x + expanded.size.x / 2,
                expanded.position.y + expanded.size.y / 2
            );

        if (normal.x != 0) {
            let c = ((ball_center.y - paddle_center.y) / (expanded.size.y / 2)) * g.BALL_MAX_ANGLE;
            this.ball.velocity.x = normal.x * Math.cos(c) * g.BALL_SPEED_MAX;
            this.ball.velocity.y = Math.sin(c) * g.BALL_SPEED_MAX;
        } else if (normal.y != 0) {
            let c = ((ball_center.x - paddle_center.x) / (expanded.size.x / 2)) * g.BALL_MAX_ANGLE;
            this.ball.velocity.x = Math.sin(c) * g.BALL_SPEED_MAX;
            this.ball.velocity.y = normal.y * Math.cos(c) * g.BALL_SPEED_MAX;
        }
    }
```

I am looking for algorithms / strategies / techniques to make the AI more capable. I don't want to use machine learning. More specifically, I would like to improve rule A, so that the AI does not just go back to the center of the board but maybe try to predict where the player will send the ball and start going towards that area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are creating a Pong version that includes special physics you could use simple maths instead of a complete simulation...

The movement of the ball is linear and constant, it will just bounce off the walls but bounces only create a change in the horizontal direction. This can be expressed using a simple Triangle Wave.

```
y = abs( (freq*x + phase) % 2 - 1) * scale - offset
```

- freq is the frequency, the amount of time it bounces in one X.
- phase moves the origin on the Y
- scale is the amplitude of the wave
- offset moves the origin on the X

With this, we can substitute some variables already.

- We will make the line bounce off the walls, which means the scale should be the width of the board.
- We will not use the offset, as this would be to get relative coordinates but we want absolute ones.

Now we also need to calculate the frequency, at what rate will the ball bounce... For this we calculate how much Y will it have to traverse to travel a full board's width. We can also simplify by just using the ratio they produce and divide them by the scale.

```
freq = ballVelocityX / ballVelocityY / scale
```

Last but not least we need to change the phase to get the origin perfectly aligned with the position of the ball. This will be between -1 and 1 depending on the direction and we'll convert to between 0 and 2.

```
phase = ballX / BOARD_WIDTH
```

The final result, in one formula by inverting X and Y:

```
x = abs( ((ballVelocityX / ballVelocityY / BOARD_WIDTH)* y + ballX / BOARD_WIDTH) % 2 - 1) * BOARD_WIDTH
```

Now to use it, we just need to use the Y distance between the ball and the paddle and we'll receive the X where the ball will end.

EDIT:

I was writing this answer while you changed your question. Since the ball's X will not change direction when a paddle is hit, it is very easy to figure out no matter the number of paddle hits it will have. Basically, you just sum the total distance and pass that to the formula. So if the board is 100 long and the balls is 10 away from the player's paddle, simple calculate for a distance of 110.

Here's the graph I played with to see it in action.
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zr3g9wumrn

```
function getTargetX(){
    let distance = this.game.ball.velocity.y <0 ? this.game.player1.position.y-this.game.ball.position.y + g.BOARD_HEIGHT : this.game.ball.position.y -this.game.player2.position.y;
    return Math.abs( ((this.game.ball.velocity.x / this.game.ball.velocity.y / BOARD_WIDTH)* distance + this.game.ball.position.x / g.BOARD_WIDTH) % 2 - 1) * g.BOARD_WIDTH
}
```

EDIT 2:

To be able to account for the change of direction when hitting a paddle, which in this answer was considered a simple Y inversion, you could calculate where the ball will be when hitting the paddle and calculate the min-max range of the paddles length that can possibly hit the ball when considering the remaining time the paddle has to move before hit.

Since we do not know if the paddle movement is a force applied or a constant vector I can't really tell the strategy to calculate it. The min-max will then allow you to calculate the min/max angle at which the ball will bounce the paddle.

The AI could then make sure to cover the most dangerous angle, which will be 90degrees since that would make the ball hit the paddle the fastest. That degree can then be used to create the possible new ball vector to use in the formula. This will provide the fastest collision point.

You could also use the min-max angles to calculate let's say 10 different degrees in that arc and average the collision points. That would provide with the most probable position of the collision. The AI would then adjust the next second but would already be somewhat close.

You can combine the two and use a weighted average to give better importance to a position according to a ratio between time for paddle to get there VS time for ball to get there. That would make a ball go almost horizontally have way less impact on the calculated average, because it will certainly take multiple seconds to reach de collision point, so adjustments will have time to happen.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you may need to tweak the numbers slightly to take into account the diameter of the ball. Basically you'd like to subtract that from the board_width and offset the result by its radius.

Comment: Thank you for your answer which will prove useful to make computation of the intersection point more efficient. Unfortunately it seems my original question was not clear enough as I am looking for ways and ideas to make the AI more capable.

Comment: Knowing the next exact point of contact from an observation can let you make it more capable... There is no more to it, it's just a Pong game after all. What more would you want than that? With the use of the formula here you can evaluate the point of contact of the next 2 balls, and position the paddle to cover for the next hit and be closest to the hit after that one. No more backing to center thing.

Comment: "try to predict where the player will send the ball and start going towards that area." That's exactly what I answered.

Comment: Ok I think I see how the formula could be useful, but doesn't it depends on two important factors: 
+ That player's paddle is already on the ball's trajectory when we look at the state.
+ That the player's paddle does not move at all between the time we look at the state and the time the collision really occurs.

If condition two is not met for exemple and the player's paddle move before the collision happens, after the bounce the ball will have a different angle and might not end up where we predicted it would be.

Comment: You are right, if the paddle makes the trajectory change, then the prediction would be useless. I did not take this into account. What you could do is estimate the change of direction by using the current player's paddle position and the collision point. You could define the most dangerous angle (I'd think 90deg) and position there, laying more to the left or right depending on the current trajectory. We don't know enough of your Pong rules to help... Like is the ball speed constant?

Comment: I have updated my OP to add more information about the game's physics. Yes the ball's speed is always constant.

Comment: I have added some thoughts for you to dig deeper.

Answer (score 0):

you can predict the position of the ball so your AI can react quickly even with checking the game state only once every second...
Im not sure about your games infrastructure and how everything is calculated but this should give you a vague idea of what im trying to do...
This will result in quicker reactions

funtion to predict the ball location:

```
predictBallPositionAfterSecond() {
    // Clone the ball's position and velocity to not affect the actual game state
    let predictedPosition = {...this.game.ball.position};
    let predictedVelocity = {...this.game.ball.velocity};

    let timeRemaining = 1.0; // Predict for 1 second into the future
    const dt = 0.016; // Assuming a frame rate of 60 FPS, so each tick is approximately 1/60th of a second

    while (timeRemaining > 0) {
        // Calculate time to next collision with top or bottom wall
        let timeToCollision;
        if (predictedVelocity.y > 0) {
            // Moving downwards
            timeToCollision = (g.BOARD_HEIGHT - g.BOARD_WALL - predictedPosition.y - this.game.ball.size.y) / predictedVelocity.y;
        } else {
            // Moving upwards
            timeToCollision = (g.BOARD_WALL - predictedPosition.y) / predictedVelocity.y;
        }

        // If no collision within the next tick, move ball for the entire tick
        if (timeToCollision > dt || timeToCollision < 0) {
            predictedPosition.x += predictedVelocity.x * dt;
            predictedPosition.y += predictedVelocity.y * dt;
            timeRemaining -= dt;
        } else {
            // Move ball to the point of collision
            predictedPosition.x += predictedVelocity.x * timeToCollision;
            predictedPosition.y += predictedVelocity.y * timeToCollision;

            // Reflect the ball's velocity
            predictedVelocity.y *= -1;

            // Subtract the elapsed time to collision from the remaining time
            timeRemaining -= timeToCollision;
        }

        // Check for collision with left and right walls to reverse X direction if necessary
        // This part can be adjusted based on your game's rules about side wall bounces
        if (predictedPosition.x <= g.BOARD_WALL || predictedPosition.x + this.game.ball.size.x >= g.BOARD_WIDTH - g.BOARD_WALL) {
            predictedVelocity.x *= -1;
        }
    }

    return predictedPosition;
}
```

Use of the predict function in your code:

```
if (elapsed >= 1000) {
    this.reset();
    this.load_state(game);

    // Predict the ball's position
    const predictedPosition = this.predictBallPositionAfterSecond();

    // Now you can use predictedPosition to decide how the AI should move
}
```

Keep in mind that for precise predictions, you'll need to tweak the collision and bounce logic to match your game's rules. Basically, the better your prediction mimics your game's physics, the more accurate it will be.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I wanted to know. My original question was not very clear so I updated it.

Comment: You can still apply what I have added as a answer just add a check whether the predicted location is in the coordinates of player or AIs field so that you can just apply either rule A or B @Emperor_Udan